# Best Practice in Captcha Recognition

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, tesseract

I am working on a real project for text-based captcha recognition.

The image processing step is roughly designed as

1. preprocess the grayscale image (dilate, erode or blur etc), in order to remove tiny noise.
2. crop if there is any border padding around the content
3. calculate the histogram according to the horizontal axis and try to crack the text vertically.
4. recognize single characters using tools like tesseract.

Currently I am coding in Python+Opencv, and I got the result as following:

[image: captcha processing]

So I have got the histogram now, If I fill some holes in the numbers, each text will nicely be shown as a normal distribution in the histogram.

But how can I actually find out the each local maximum value in this image? Currently the histogram is discrete and not that smooth. I am now stuck in this stage.

And also, those noise strips cannot be removed. Because the texts are in different colors. So do I need to convert the color space into HSV or anything else?

I would greatly appreciate it if you kindly give me some suggestion.

Thank you!

Comment: @Piglet It's not about the purpose. I am only discussing on the "lock techniques".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.. Try looking into how the image looks like in various layers of HSV. Apply histogram equalization/contrast normalization to the value layer, threshold and see if there is a difference.